# Is there way to mock object without extending with Mock class in Flutter?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, mockito

I have question about mocking. In kotlin when you use Mockito you can do

```
val someMock: MyType = mock()
```

or

```
someFunction(mock())
```

Is there way to do something like this in dart/flutter?
I really just need to pass mock to some function and forget, why i must create object and extending it with Mock class?

Is there any other library which helps with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not feasible.

While you can mock everything with Mockito (including functions), you cannot escape the need to extend `Mock`.